# How to convert a sound file to any other data format which can be manipulated

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, frequency, sound

I know this is very basic question and i am new to this site. But can anybody help me with my question. How to convert a sound file to other data format say using some type of transform (FFT or DFT) with which i can manipulate the data of the sound. Lets say i get frequency values from the sound i should be able to manipulate or compare these values to another sound file which is again converted to the same format so i can compare these two. Are there any algorithms to do this.

Comment: What format is the sound file in currently?  If it is in wav format you may be able to just read it into most signal processing languages (Matlab/Python/probably Mathematica/etc) and manipulate the data there, using whatever transform you wish.

Comment: Yes it is wav file. Can you recommend me any transformation which can be done in c or c++ .

Comment: You say you'd like to compare two audio files. What exactly do you intend to compare?

Comment: I think you may need to re-word your question.  If it is in wav format you probably don't need to convert to any other format.  It now sounds like you want to transform the audio signal into some other domain in order to alter it in some way.  You can manipulate the signal directly if you want to, or if you have a particular goal, then you may need to use a particular transform.  But you haven't said what you want to manipulate or compare.

Comment: I want to compare two sound files which will be recorded through microphone. If two sounds are equal then do further processing. So is there any thing to compare direct two sounds or should i convert these sounds to another format using some transformation and then compare ?